# sudo gacutil permissions

Tags: macos, sudo, gacutil

I am trying to use gacutil on my mac. When I do I get the error:

```
gac directories could not be created, possibly permission issues.
```

So how do I get the permission, considering this is my computer?! There are two users on the computer, geoff and admin. I tried:

```
sudo gacutil -i mysql.data.dll
```

then gave the admin's password, but I got

```
Sorry, try again.
```

which I did to no avail. So how can I get this to work?

Comment: how did you get `gac` to be available on OSX in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was nothing to do with gacutil or sudo, but somehow my username did not match my account name. After posting on another part of the exchange I found the problem and its answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76068/whoami-is-not-who-i-am

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` requires the password of the current user, not the admin password.

Comment: But it still doesn't work. It does give me a strange message though: `org1 is not in the sudoers file.` So who is this org1; or more to the point, why is my computer asking me this since org1 is my work login name, but I do not login as such on my computer at home?!

Comment: Does your company use a domain controller of some sort? Try `reset` in the terminal or completely closing the terminal and reopening it to clear the envrionment.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am answering correctly, but all the same: if I want to use my comp in work I can use VPN and login that way, using org1. But at the moment I have no VPN connection open. My terminals though have as prompt: `Geoffs-MacBook-Air:v4 org1$`.

Comment: Oh and the `reset` didn't. It tells me how to delete and interrupt.

Comment: You seem be logged into it still. As I'm not familiar with the vpn software you are using I can't really help you, but you should be fine once you manage to get to your normal user again.

Comment: After much struggle I resolved my username problems. Now I am geoff BUT I still have the permission problems with gacutil.